# Drawable icons aren't displayed on Button

Tags: android, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

Everytime I try to add some drawable icons to a button they are not displayed even if it's a button or a Material Button

```
   <Button
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Person"
                  android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_person_pin_circle_black_24dp"
                  />
              <Button
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center"
                  android:text="Package"
                  android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                  android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_business_center_black_24dp"
                  />
```

In the left I have the "pin person" icon and the "briefcase " icon, but on the layout aren't display. Do you know what might cause this?

Comment: In the MaterialButton you have to use app:icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drawableStart corresponds to the **drawable that will be draw to the begenning** of the view **according to the layout direction**, but your direction could be bad ; you can change this direction like that :

android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|left"

**or you can add them programmatically :**

```
myButton.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(
    ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_business_center_black_24dp), null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `MaterialButton` use the **`app:icon`** attribute and the **`app:iconGravity="start"`**.

Something like:

```
  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
        app:icon="@drawable/..."
        app:iconGravity="start"
        ../>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much